# Pip Package not available in conda

Tags: python, pip, package, conda, oct2py

I'm creating a conda environment from a requirements file and it keeps throwing errors trying to find oct2py. 
I've used

```
conda search oct2py
```

which returns no result, but when I try

```
pip search oct2py
```

I can see that the correct version of oct2py is installed.
I'm wondering how I can make conda find the oct2py package? Or do I need to reinstall it with conda? If I have to reinstall oct2py, will this affect the current installation and current usage?

Comment: `pip` can install from file `.whl` downloaded on local disc - `pip install oct2py.whl`. Maybe `conda` can do it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install using `pip` the package will reside in your default python folder under `/path/to/python/Lib/site-packages`. But Conda resides in a whole different folder with a similar structure so `/path/to/conda/Lib/site-packages`. The code you run will pick up on which directory you have in your path. You can install using conda with the command `conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/ioos oct2py`